# How can a web user be authenticated through their machine without providing a username and password?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-membership

I'm wondering how I can authenticate a user through their device, so they don't have to provide a username and password?

For example I'm on an Android tablet and I connect to www.mysite.com (which is an asp.net site).  I want the web browser to submit something to www.mysite.com to handle the authentication so the user doesn't have to put in a username and password and can only use the service from the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our use case we were able to control the url passed to the server.  To initiate the process we have the user login once and we generate a guid to be appended to the url when they initially hit our site.  When they hit our site with a guid and aren't logged in, we log them in.